# Conversion from byte to ASCII in Java

Tags: java, compression, byte

I'm working on a university project and I have to print some words on a File starting from their bit value. The problem is I can't print the special charachters like letters with accents. I even tried running this simple main to check what was wrong but can't seem to find it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("dex.txt"), "UTF-8"));

    byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(new File("ex.txt").toPath());
    BitSet decompressed = BitSet.valueOf(b);
    byte[] v = decompressed.toByteArray();
    writer.write((char) v[0]);
    writer.close();
}
```

The file `ex.txt` has simply the character `é` in it but what I get after the conversion is `ï¿©`.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you opening the `dex.txt` file in, and how does it know that the file is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: I'm opening it with eclipse since it's in the project directory. Notepad shows another charachter `￩`

Comment: First of all the conversion of byte[] into BitSet and then back to byte[] seems useless to me (i.e. you will get the same byte[] you started with). What was your intention to do that? Second: The character é in UTF-8 consists of 2 Bytes (c3, a9). Your code will only pick the first byte (c3) than cast it to char, wich results in ffc3 (because of sign Extension) which is a hangul letter and probably your Editor could not Display this correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to compress text using LZ78 and decompress it. I compress it correctly but the special characters are shown in a wrong way so I tried to replicate only the part I was interested in.

Comment: What does “print some words on a File starting from their bit value” mean?  Can you edit your question to show an example of the output you wish to see?